# subfloat reference label language?

Tags: xetex, subfloats, polyglossia

I want to get russian subreferences in subfloats:

[image]

I think it should be provided by

```
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
```

but it doesn't work. Here's a full minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setromanfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% Russian/English document:
\usepackage{xecyr}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Arial}

\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[lofdepth]{subfig}

\usepackage[russian]{hyperref}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{Dummy figure}\label{subfig:1}
  }
  \subfloat[][]{\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{Dummy figure}\label{subfig:2}
  }
  \caption[]{I want subfloat links to be russian: (а) and (б) instead of (a) and (b).\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\asbuk{subfigure}}
```

after `\usepackage[lofdepth]{subfig}`. For subtables, use also

```
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\asbuk{subtable}}
```

[image]

You might want to ping Arthur Reutenauer at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia asking for including `\asbuk` in the documentation of Polyglossia.

---

Note. Avoid `\setromanfont` and `\setdefaultlanguage`, which simply do again what `\setmainfont` and `\setmainlanguage` specified. They are obsolete commands, retained for backward compatibility.

Comment: I opened [an issue](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/34) for polyglossia@github.